# NSMutableAttributedString addAttribute for range apply for all string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have created NSMutableAttributedString with different attributes and then for one range I added attribute with bold font. Example

```
let attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.Branding.darkText,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ])
        if let word = string.components(separatedBy: " ").first {
            let range = attText.mutableString.range(of: word, options: .caseInsensitive)
            if range.location != NSNotFound {
                attText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold), range: range)
            }
        }
```

But when I launched application I saw all string with bold font. I saw attributed string in debug and it looked like this:

```
 some : Create{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.247059 0.278431 0.337255 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ff1c1c169e0> font-family: \".SFUIText-Semibold\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}
tasks for people{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.247059 0.278431 0.337255 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7ff1c1c388d0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}
```

As I understood debug information is okay, but why in iOS simulator I see all string with bold font?

Comment: Where did you set `myLabelOrTextView.attributedText = attText`?

Comment: I don't leave code with setting attributed text, but in debug info you can see attributed text of my label. So it has set correctly.

Comment: Are you setting at some point `label.font`?

Comment: Only in interface builder. And this font is Regular not bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the document of `attributedText` of UILabel:

```
  label.attributedText =  attText
  ``label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)
  print(label.attributedText)
```

After setting attributedText of UILabel, you cannot change font , textColor or other style related property. Otherwise you will get what you have now.
My guess is in some place there is a modification overlooked.

Comment: But I don't change font,textcolor and other after setting attributed text

Comment: You may change some where and you did not know. But this is the only reason I can repeat the problem, You may extract the VC to a fresh project and play around.

Comment: Yee, really, I added observer and found code where set attributed string after my settings. Thank you!